While travelling from India to Amsterdam via Frankfurt, can the baggage be booked through to the final destination Amsterdam?
I will be travelling to Amsterdam via Paris from India. Both legs of journey are on the same airline.
Can my baggage be booked through to the final destination Amsterdam without having to clear customs at Frankfurt.

Could you clarify where Frankfurt comes into the picture please.  Your question says you are travelling from India to Amsterdam via Paris.

Whether it is Paris or Frankfurt, as long as the flights are on the same ticket, your luggage should be checked through to your final destination, and on such a scenario you won’t see it.
Note that I wrote “same ticket”, not “same airline”:

some airlines, in particular low-cost carriers, will only sell point-to-point tickets, without connections, so two successive flights with such an airline would not see your luggage checked through. I think that’s unlikely in your case, but we don’t have the details.
Even with flights on different airlines, as long as they “interline” and the flights are on the same ticket they will usually check your luggage through.

On traditional airlines, flights ticketed separately on the same airline (or within the same alliance) can sometimes be checked through, but that is a lot more variable.
Note that in the EU, in the vast majority of cases (and definitely here), contrary to the US for instance, while you will go through passport control at your  point of entry into the EU (Frankfurt or Paris), your luggage will go through customs at your final destination. No need to claim your bags and re-check them at the connection airport.
